# User Object - Unable to grant permissions to some fields in Profile

Tags: permissions, user-record, omnistudio

I have a flow in the Omnistudio stack where we extract and pre-populate the omniscript with information from the User object: name, phone, company, etc...

This is not working in one of our orgs, so I think it is likely a permissions issue.

In Setup > profiles configuration I am unable to see (and grant access to) some fields on the User Object.  Does anyone know how to grant access to these fields?

Screenshot from Profile configuration showing that 'Phone' is missing.  [image]

Screenshot from the Custom Object configuration showing the 'Phone' field.[image]

Comment: related : this [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdWd3UAF/need-ability-to-set-field-security-on-user-object)